# Spring: Why I cant check for spring boot version without an error?

Tags: spring-boot, cygwin

I am follow the guide for setting up spring boot with the following link.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-installing-the-cli
section 10.2.2

when I type $ spring --version 
I receive the error below.
/cygdrive/c/Users/Jesse/Documents/.sdkman/candidates/springboot/current/bin/spring: line 83: [: C:\Program: binary operator expected
Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher

Comment: It looks like you're on Windows and using Cygwin. Have you tried using `spring.bat` in a standard Windows shell instead?

Comment: Fixed. I needed to set the environment variable. SPRING_HOME.

Comment: I think Andy Wilkinson's comment should be an answer.  Solved the exact same issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the SPRING_HOME variable.

After setting, SPRING_HOME was not resolving correctly for me even though it was set in windows as a user and a system variable, and was also visible when running `export` via Git Bash. I ended up replacing the last line in my spring.sh file, essentialy forcing the classpath for the java command:

```
"${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java" ${JAVA_OPTS} -cp "/drive_letter/dir/to/spring/spring-x.x.x.RELEASE/lib/spring-boot-cli-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar" org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher "$@"
```